# How do I make an Ajax call using the serialized value?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have truly been at this for days with no luck. I have never worked with jQuery or AJAX before so I am lost as to how to use

```
    $('#serialize').click(function(){
        serialized = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable('serialize');
        $('#serializeOutput').text(serialized+'\n\n');
    })
```

to use the serialized data that is output to the screen to make an Ajax call.

This is my first post to the forum so please excuse me if I don't include all that I am expected to.

Here is link to my page: http://web-dev.cals.ncsu.edu/kimTEST/newsortable.cfm

Try as I might, I cannot get my code to post properly on the page. Hopefully the link will suffice.

Thanks

Comment: I think your question is too broad. I understand that you're using jQuery, AJAX, and ColdFusion -- but not all of these are giving you a problem, so it is best to reduce your question to just what you are having trouble with. ColdFusion doesn't seem relevant to your difficulty, so I'd recommend dropping it from the question. If you're not successfully retrieving data from the AJAX call, frame it as an AJAX question. Or if you're having trouble parsing a successful return from AJAX, frame it as a jQuery question.

Comment: Thanks...I'll rephrase the question

Comment: How about reading the tutorial? http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ That's their purpose: To teach you about something you don't know.

Comment: What does `nestedSortable()` do?

Comment: The nested sortable allows for a three tiered display and sort of a list with drag and drop.  An example may be found at http://web-dev.cals.ncsu.edu/kimTEST/newsortable.cfm

Answer (score 0):

I found exactly what I was looking for on Cory Fail's web site:
http://coryfail.com/coldfusion-basic-jquery-ajax/#comment-354

If anyone needs assistance, I will be glad to share my code.